# Backbone Client Side Collection Filtering

Tags: backbone.js

Consider a backbone app that has a `select` list of categories, and a table of files underneath it. All files, regardless of the category they belong to are in the `App.collection.files` collection. When a user selects a new category, I'd like to filter the table to only show those matching files.

I'd like to do this completely on the client side. I do NOT want to fetch a new list of files from the server each time a new category is picked.

I plan to to a `App.collection.files.where({category_id: xx})` within `App.View.Files.render()` to accomplish the filtering itself.

What is the best Backbone-y way to trigger/respond to an event to get this working?

One idea I am playing with is another collection, that contains the filtered files, but not sure if this is the best approach.

```
App.View.FilesPage = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: App.utils.template('files-page'),
    className: 'container-fluid',
    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template());

        this.$el.find('.categories').append(
            new App.View.Categories({collection:App.collection.categories}).el
        );

        this.$el.find('.files table').append(
            new App.View.Files({collection:App.collection.files}).el
        );

        return this;
    }
});

App.View.Categories = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'select',
    events: {
        'change': 'onChange'
    },
    initialize: function(){
        this.$el.attr('size', this.collection.length + 1);

        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        var option = function(value, text, isSelected){
            return $('<option></option>', {'value':value, 'text':text});
        };

        this.$el.html(option(0, 'All Documents'));

        this.$el.append(
            this.collection.invoke(function(){
                return option(this.get('category_id'), this.get('title'));
            })
        ).val(0);

        return this;
    },
    onChange: function(event){

    }
});

App.View.Files = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tbody',
    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){         
        this.$el.html(
            this.collection.invoke(function(){
                return new App.View.File({model:this}).el;
            })
        );

        return this;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution I came up with, that seems fine and dandy on the surface.

Code changes are called out within comments.

Thoughts on this solution, and completely different solutions are welcome.

```
App.View.FilesPage = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: App.utils.template('files-page'),
    className: 'container-fluid',
    initialize: function(){
        // CHANGE: Store application wide reference to 'Categories' model
        App.model.categories = new App.Model.Categories();

        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template());

        this.$el.find('.categories').append(
            new App.View.Categories({
                // CHANGE: Pass model into 'Categories' view
                model: App.model.categories,
                collection: App.collection.categories
            }).el
        );

        this.$el.find('.files table').append(
            new App.View.Files({collection:App.collection.files}).el
        );

        return this;
    }
});

App.View.Categories = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'select',
    events: {
        'change': 'onChange'
    },
    initialize: function(){         
        this.$el.attr('size', this.collection.length + 1);

        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        var option = function(value, text, isSelected){
            return $('<option></option>', {'value':value, 'text':text});
        };

        this.$el.html(option(0, 'All Documents'));

        this.$el.append(
            this.collection.invoke(function(){
                return option(this.get('category_id'), this.get('title'));
            })
        ).val(0);

        return this;
    },
    onChange: function(){
        // CHANGE: Update attribute within 'Categories' model
        this.model.set('category_id', this.$el.val());
    }
});

App.View.Files = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tbody',
    initialize: function(){     
        this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
        // CHANGE: Listen for change on 'Categories' model, and re-render this view
        App.model.categories.on('change:category_id', this.render, this);

        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(
            _.invoke(this.getFilteredFiles(), function(){
                return new App.View.File({model:this}).el;
            })
        );

        return this;
    },
    // CHANGE: Return a filtered set of models from collection, based on 'Categories' model attributes
    getFilteredFiles: function(){
        var categoryId = App.model.categories.get('category_id');

        if (categoryId!=0){
            return this.collection.where({'category_id': categoryId});
        }
        else{
            return this.collection.models;
        }
    }
});
```